# How To Get The Newest Gmail Design

Tags: gmail, user-interface

I came across this beautiful light Gmail design:

[image]

Does anyone know if this was just an experiment or will this be rolling out someday?

Because my Gmail looks currently like this (every email has a dark background and everything is tight together in general, many spacer lines, etc.):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the perfect solution, but at least some design improvement, achieved with the Chrome add-on by Michael Leggett, former Gmail lead designer (release just after Inbox was dropped, which says it all, I guess)

https://www.theverge.com/2019/4/26/18517631/gmail-simplify-inbox-by-google-simple-michael-leggett-user-interface-design

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is how it will be since Gmail looks like that for me for a few weeks already. I really love the new design!

All the best,
AOVCrystals

Comment: Awesome! Looking forward to it :)

Comment: Can't wait to finally get my hands on the new design...looking at the current design feels just wrong. I am used to Inbox, so using the current Gmail was a huge downgrade for me

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to invite others to activate the new design (like it is sometimes possible with beta versions)?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't already... go to the settings cog and select Themes, then be sure you have the Default selected.

That should get you the newest version available.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, I already have the default theme, looks like I just have to wait a bit (I live in Switzerland, so it may be a bit delayed here)